# How to check a procedure/view/table exists or not before dropping it in db2 9.1?

Tags: database, db2

How do we write below pseudo code in db2,

```
If (Proc exists)
  Drop Proc
  Create Proc
Else
 Create Proc
```

One solution I found, after googling is to ignore the return codes. Do we have a more elegant way to do this?

Thanks

---

Update: With the help of the answer below we wrote a proc as below to drop the procedures

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE SVCASNDB.DROPSP(IN P_SPECIFICNAME VARCHAR(128))
        SPECIFIC DROPSP

        P1: BEGIN


        -- Drop the SP if it already exists
        if exists (SELECT SPECIFICNAME FROM SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES WHERE SPECIFICNAME = trim(upper(p_SpecificName))) then
            begin
                DECLARE v_StmtString VARCHAR (1024);
                SET v_StmtString = 'DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE SCHEMA.' || p_SpecificName;
                PREPARE stmt1 FROM v_StmtString ;
                EXECUTE stmt1;
            end;
        end if;

    END P1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROUTINENAME, RESULT_SETS, REMARKS 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINESCHEMA='<schema>' AND FUNCTION_TYPE NOT IN ('S', 'T')
```

(where you specify your schema name at the  placeholder)
gives you all procs in a schema. So the Proc exists part is simply an EXISTS query on that view with the proper proc name.