# Drop a DB2 view if it exists

Tags: sql, db2

Why doesn't this work in [IBM Data Studio (Eclipse)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-studio/features.html):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSVIEWS WHERE NAME = 'MYVIEW' AND CREATOR = 'MYSCHEMA') THEN
    DROP VIEW MYSCHEMA.MYVIEW;
END IF;
```

I have a feeling it has to do with statement terminators (;) but I can't find a syntax that works.

Another similar question at [How to check a procedure/view/table exists or not before dropping it in db2 9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355687/how-to-check-a-procedure-view-table-exists-or-not-before-dropping-it-in-db2-9-1) suggests that they had to create a proc but this isn't a solution for us.

Comment: Is this DB2 for iSeries or DB2 for the other platforms? It matters because there is some difference.

Comment: Our DB2 server is on AIX, but I run IBM Data Studio on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

from IBM's Book: [Getting Started with Data Studio for DB2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/db2oncampus/FREE+ebook+-+Getting+started+with+IBM+Data+Studio+for+DB2):

> Statement terminator: You can develop
>   multiple SQL statements in a single
>   SQL Editor window by ending each
>   statement with a statement terminator
>   character. The default terminator is a
>   semi-colon. But you can change that to
>   another character by right-clicking in
>   the contents of the editor and
>   selecting the context menu action Set
>   Statement Terminator.

**EDIT:**

OK, the problem seems to be the syntax. Many people seem to have the same problem. Example see [DROP TABLE, VIEW, ... only IF EXISTS](http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/509144-drop-table-view-only-if-exists).

In the example there are two solutions mentioned.

1. use `Begin atomic`
2. use the procedure `db2perf_quiet_drop`

For details read the liked page.

**Second EDIT:**

I just found a really good explanation for `Begin ataomic` on the IBM pages. See [Advanced SQL Scripting PL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0203yip/0203yip.html) from IBM. Example 2 is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is something along the lines of the sql processor doesn't like the statement terminator inside of the if...end if, but I'm only guessing. What I really need is a db2 valid sql statement that will check that a view exists before dropping it.

Comment: From what I can see of that Example 2, it describes how to feed an SQL statement stored in a text file, to the DB2 command line client. It's interesting but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It shows you how to wrap the `if` statement with `begin atomic`. It also states that you have to use a different Statement terminator. In addition it shows you that even the statement terminator was changed to `@` you need to use the `;` for the statement that is wrapped by `begin atomic`.